# filter emails and names and then de-duplicate in two columns using JSON on PostgreSQL 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have `emails` table that has `sender` and `reporter` columns. I want to search given parameter in those columns and return unique values.

Let me explain with sample. This is my table and records:

```
CREATE TABLE public.emails (
  id                bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807),
  sender            jsonb NOT NULL,
  reporter      jsonb not null
);

insert into emails (sender, reporter) VALUES ('[{"email": "dennis1@example.com", "name": "dennis1"}]', '[]');
insert into emails (sender, reporter) VALUES ('[{"email": "dennis2@example.com", "name": "dennis1"}]', '[{"email": "john@example.com", "name": "john"}, {"email": "dennis1@example.com", "name": "dennis1"}, {"email": "dennis2@example.com", "name": "dennis2"}]');
insert into emails (sender, reporter) VALUES ('[{"email": "dennis1@example.com", "name": "dennis1"}]', '[]');
insert into emails (sender, reporter) VALUES ('[{"email": "dennis1@example.com", "name": "dennis1"}]', '[]');
```

I want to get email addresses and names. I also want to avoid dupes. Only one email and one name. I also don't want to get it as array, instead, one email and name per one row.

#### Searching `john`

```sql
SELECT
* /* i don't know what to put here pr merge with reporters */
FROM "emails" AS "e"
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT
    *
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT("e"."sender") AS "e" ("email")
  WHERE ("e"."email" ~* 'john' or "e"."name" ~* 'john'))
);
```

#### Expected Result for `john`:

```
email                 name
john@example.com      john
```

---

#### Searching for `` (empty):

```sql
SELECT
* /* i don't know what to put here pr merge with reporters */
FROM "emails" AS "e"
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT
    *
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT("e"."sender") AS "e" ("email")
  WHERE ("e"."email" ~* '' or "e"."name" ~* ''))
);
```

#### Expected Result for `` (empty):

```
email                 name
john@example.com      john
dennis1@example.com   dennis1
dennis2@example.com   dennis2
```

`dennis2` is in both `sender` and `reporter`, therefore, only one of them is required. No dupes.

In fact, in here there is one catch. If `sender` or `reporter` columns has at least one json object (not json array) then this query also fails.

#### Error: `cannot extract elements from an object`

Which is an another story, tho.

How can i achieve my goal in this case?

#### Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1bf9c5f83f5104e2392c31984cb4e939

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6173b070fc4b377a67fc1db017f11e63 It is not clear how to deal with pairs `dennis1 - dennis2@example.com`, `dennis2 - dennis2@example.com` and `dennis1 - dennis1@example.com`: pair `dennis1 - dennis2@example.com` duplicates what?

Comment: Ah, name and email can be anything. This is why im searching on both fields using `OR`. We need to check dupes based on `email`. If email present more than 1 time, regardless of its name, only first or last or randomly selected. So one only. I forgot to say that. So Sorry. Can we pick last or first match?

Comment: Is is what you mean https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=43b1cd633d014bb180dedf4bf016b2ab ?

Comment: Exactly! You used `||` operator in function to merge columns. I didn't know that. Wow. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: P.S.: If `senders` or `reporters` is `NULL` it fails :( See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aaaf68cb11a7b931634be1f57b371530

Comment: Yes, it fails because of `not null` constraint. What is your question?

Comment: @Abelisto Sorry man! I'm sleepless at the moment i didn't get attention to that. Sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize your data before searching, then remove duplicates using [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause:

```
with cte as (select x ->> 'name' as name, x ->> 'email' as email
from emails as e, jsonb_array_elements(e.sender || e.reporter) as x)
select distinct on (email) * from cte where 
  name ~* '' or email ~* ''
  --name ~* 'john' or email ~* 'john'
order by email;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b12daf037699c7e271ac77bcbf5db33b)</kbd>

Note that it will always scan the whole table, no indexes applicable in this case. Think about [schema normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I already did that (normalization) the question contains complete draft queries and table schema. I will take care of it.